# Solspace freeform & solspace calendar

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace-calendar

Is it possible to use freeform like channel form to add events to calendar? My goal is to include in my freeform form to allow clients to request an appt on the calendar ?

Answer (score 1):

Solspace Calendar is **not** a module that allows making "reservations" or "appointments". It's a module that allows creating **events** in a calendar.

The only form that allows creating **events** from the front-end if Channel Forms. Freeform cannot create Calendar events.

Comment: Is this still valid? I need to do same schema. I need flexibility of freeform pro and ability to create event in calendar. This would be really awesome.

Comment: Calendar still does not allow this

Comment: Too bad. Really it would be great if you can use them both